# rainbow.js doesn't run Rainbow.color(); on startup

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, rainbow-js

I'm using - or maybe I'm trying to use the `rainbow.js` syntax highlighting library for the code snippets I publish on my blog (`Google Blogger`). I think I'm using it correctly:

```
<pre><code data-language="python">
// here goes the code
</code></pre>
```

And all needed libraries are loaded in `HTML` HEAD section:

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rainbow/1.1.8/themes/github.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rainbow/1.1.8/js/rainbow.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rainbow/1.1.8/js/language/generic.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rainbow/1.1.8/js/language/python.min.js"></script>
...
```

An example post I've got problems with is [this one](http://sys-exit.blogspot.com/2013/11/mocking-api-with-sinonjs.html). The code is wrapped in pre/code tags and the background is grey - so CSS is supposed to be loaded correctly. But there is no highlighting actually. But when I type the following:

```
Rainbow.color();
```

manually in the `JavaScript` console, colors (syntax highlighting) does appear. I don't know what's wrong, can anybody give me a hint?

---

edit:

I have added the following right before :

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
  window.onload=function(){ Rainbow.color(); };
  Rainbow.color();
</script>
```

Unfortunately, neither onload nor manual `Rainbow.color();` works...

Answer (score 1):

You already have all the pieces. From [the documentation](http://craig.is/making/rainbows/):

> `Rainbow.color`
>
> This method is called to highlight all the blocks on the page on load.
>   **If you would like to highlight stuff that is not in the DOM you can
>   call it on its own.** There are three ways to use it.
>
> One option is adding new code blocks to the DOM and then calling the
>   method again:
>
> ```
> // alone
> Rainbow.color();
>
> // or with a call back
> Rainbow.color(function() {
>     console.log('the new blocks are now highlighted!');
> });
> ```

When you execute scripts in `<head>` there's no `<body>` yet.

Answer (score 0):

Im using 'window.history' as a single page application (SPA) to load pages into index.php and had the same problem - rainbow.js doesnt color code. But if i open the page containing code directly in the browser it works.

Adding this at the end of each page after calling rainbow.js made it work when using 'window.history' - could be the same issue on a blog:

```
<script src="/scripts/rainbow-custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
    setTimeout(Rainbow.color, 1000);
</script>
```